# How to create a reusable parent and child dropdown list?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, html-select

Here is the page for this qustion: http://goo.gl/AeSF6x

I'm trying to create a dropdown list(destination) with a "Add More" button and a child dropdownlist (attractions).
When the user clicks the add more button it should duplicate the dropdown list(destination) and it's child dropdown(attractions).
The second dropdown list (destination) and it's child(attractions) will be created with a "remove" button.

When the user selects the "destination" attraction will show a list attraction which is pulled from a .txt file according to thier destination selection.

My mark up is:

```
<div id="page-wrap" class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add Destination</button>
    <br/><br/>
    <select id="text-one" name="destination[]">
        <option selected value="base">Please Select</option>
        <option value="colombo">Colombo</option>
        <option value="kandy">Kandy</option>
        <option value="anuradhapura">Anuradhapura</option>
    </select>

    <br />

    <select id="text-two" name="attraction[]">
        <option>Please choose from above</option>
    </select>
    <br/><br/>
</div>
```

And this is how the attractions are loaded from the text file:

```
<script>
    $(function() {      
        $("#text-one").change(function() {
            $("#text-two").load("textdata/" + $(this).val() + ".txt");
        });
    });
</script>
```

And for duplicate / for add more button I use following jquery code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var max_fields      = 10; //maximum dropdown allowed
        var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

        var x = 1; //initlal dropdown count
        $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add dropdown button click
            e.preventDefault();
            if(x < max_fields){ //max dropdown allowed
                x++; //dropdown increment
                $(wrapper).append('<div><select id="text-one" name="destination[]"><option selected value="base">Please Select</option><option value="colombo">Colombo</option><option value="kandy">Kandy</option><option value="anuradhapura">Anuradhapura</option></select><br /><select id="text-two"><option>Please choose from above</option></select><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a><br/><br/></div>'); //add drop down
            }
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
        })
    });
</script>
```

All working fine except loading the attractions on second dropdown list.

On the first dropdown list I am able to get the attraction according to the destination selection.

But unable to get the attractions according to 2nd, 3rd and so on dropdown list(destination)

You may see that by visiting to the page and click "Add Destination" and try to select "Attraction" : http://goo.gl/AeSF6x

What I'm doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context. Here, you are duplicating select elements IDs. Use class instead and btw delegate `change` event. Then to target relevant select two element regardin the one changed, you could use (using classes, not IDs): `$(".input_fields_wrap").on('change', '.text-one', function() {
            $(this).nextAll('.text-two').first().load("textdata/" + $(this).val() + ".txt");
        });`

Comment: I would actually say that using the ID is the way to go here but keep a counter of how many destinations you have currently and add the counter to the end of the id to avoid clashes

Comment: @DanielCasserly yes.. that's the way. But when try add a counter I'm getting some syntex errors. could you please update my code with your suggestion?

Comment: Not sure just from a glance but I can't see where you are using the counter. Is it possible to pop this into a jsFiddle and I'll take a closer look?

Comment: @A.Wolff I've created another page with your code. But it is not even getting data during the 1st time. could you check please: http://goo.gl/bziBTp You can check the page source code. It's short and well indented.

Comment: @DanielCasserly unable to call the folder **textdata** in codepen. it says "Blocked loading mixed active content"

Comment: Have you changed the change function to use the new ids? This is the tricky part.